# Kendo Scheduler with Adaptive Display takes over vertical scroll on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, kendo-ui, scheduler, durandal

I am building a responsive web app with Kendoui, Bootstrap and Durandal.

I am using Kendo Scheduler along with other elements on a page and I have enabled adaptive display on the component by setting :

mobile: true

The page scrolls fine on mobile until I get to the scheduler and then my swipes (Up-Down) seem to be swallowed by the component and I can no longer scroll the page ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the adaptive demo from Kendo the mobile property should be "phone" instead of true. Maybe that is your issue. Take a look here http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/adaptive

Comment: If you put: mobile: true, it should switch between desktop and mobile by itself. In that situation, the vertical scrolling o longer works on mobile.